# Removing icon and style of QMdiSubWindow

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets, qmdiarea

I notice that windows from QMdiarea needs to be style customized. I want to remove icon which appears on topleft of QMdiSubWindow widget and at the same time change this ugly blue color of window to something which look pretty good.

I have tried my setWindowsflag, but no effect.

**The code:**

```
class Mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Mywindow, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800,600))
        self.setWindowTitle('Customized style')
        self.mdiarea = QtWidgets.QMdiArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdiarea)
        self.mdiarea.setWindowTitle('Test')
        
        self.window = QtWidgets.QWidget()        
        self.mdiarea.addSubWindow(self.window)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    view = Mywindow()
    view.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Current Display:

[image]

Wants to obtain:

[image]

Any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least there are 2 solutions:

**1. Use Qt StyleSheet**

You must use the "background" property of QMdiSubWindow: title to change the color, and to remove the icon the trick is to pass it an icon with transparent color

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

QSS = """
QMdiSubWindow:title{
    background: lightgray;
}
"""


def create_icon_by_color(color):
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(512, 512)
    pixmap.fill(color)
    return QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)


class Mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Mywindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Customized style")
        self.mdiarea = QtWidgets.QMdiArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdiarea)
        self.mdiarea.setWindowTitle("Test")

        self.window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.window.setMinimumSize(320, 240)
        sw = self.mdiarea.addSubWindow(self.window)
        sw.setWindowIcon(create_icon_by_color(QtGui.QColor("transparent")))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    app.setStyleSheet(QSS)
    view = Mywindow()
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

As you can see in my operating system, it has a white color in the middle that is not desired that serves to color the title of the subwindow, maybe in another operating system it does not generate that problem.

**2. Use a QProxyStyle**

In this case you can modify the style so it should be a more robust solution than the previous one and should not have other styles. For a simple operation I have created a custom QMdiSubWindow.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

def create_icon_by_color(color):
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(512, 512)
    pixmap.fill(color)
    return QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)


class TitleProxyStyle(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    def drawComplexControl(self, control, option, painter, widget=None):
        if control == QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_TitleBar:
            if hasattr(widget, "titleColor"):
                color = widget.titleColor
                if color.isValid():
                    option.palette.setBrush(
                        QtGui.QPalette.Highlight, QtGui.QColor(color)
                    )
            option.icon = create_icon_by_color(QtGui.QColor("transparent"))
        super(TitleProxyStyle, self).drawComplexControl(
            control, option, painter, widget
        )


class MdiSubWindow(QtWidgets.QMdiSubWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, flags=QtCore.Qt.Widget):
        super(MdiSubWindow, self).__init__(parent, flags)
        style = TitleProxyStyle(self.style())
        self.setStyle(style)
        self._titleColor = QtGui.QColor()

    @property
    def titleColor(self):
        return self._titleColor

    @titleColor.setter
    def titleColor(self, color):
        self._titleColor = color
        self.update()


class Mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Mywindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Customized style")
        self.mdiarea = QtWidgets.QMdiArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdiarea)
        self.mdiarea.setWindowTitle("Test")

        self.window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.window.setMinimumSize(160, 120)

        sw = MdiSubWindow()
        sw.setWindowTitle("Test")
        sw.titleColor = QtGui.QColor("lightgray")
        sw.setWidget(self.window)
        self.mdiarea.addSubWindow(sw)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    view = Mywindow()
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks much for your solutions. I personally prefer second solution. It looks perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QAction, QMenuBar, QWidget,
                             QMdiArea, QMdiSubWindow, QProxyStyle, QStyle, QVBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtGui     import (QIcon, QPainter, QPalette, QPixmap)
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt, QSize


class MDIArea(QMdiArea):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MDIArea, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  
        self.parent = args[0]
        self.background_pixmap = self.parent.pixmap 
        self.centered          = False

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(self.viewport())
        if not self.centered:
            painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.background_pixmap)
        painter.end()


class Mywindow(QMainWindow):
    count = 1
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Mywindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('Customized style')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("im.png"))

#        self.mdiarea = QMdiArea()
        self.pixmap = QPixmap()
        self.pixmap.load("im.png")
        self.mdiarea = MDIArea(self)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdiarea)
#        self.mdiarea.setWindowTitle('Test')

        self.window = QWidget()   
        sub = QMdiSubWindow()
        sub.resize(QSize(200,200))
        sub.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        sub.setWidget(self.window) 
        sub.setWindowTitle("Test {}".format(self.count))            # +++
        sub.setWindowIcon(QIcon("im.png"))

        self.mdiarea.addSubWindow(sub)
        sub.show()          


style = """
QWidget {
    color: #ffdd00;
    background-color: #eee;
}
QMainWindow {
    color: #ffdd00;
    background-color: #ff3333;
}
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    app.setStyleSheet(style)          

#    app.setStyle('Fusion')                                        # ---

    view = Mywindow()
#    view.showMaximized()
    view.resize(500, 500)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your effort and option. I just want to say, that I prefer about options with QProxystyle.