# Customizing window flags of QMdiSubWindow title bar

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt6

I would like to remove the minimize and maximize buttons of the title bar of QMdiSubWindow and add a button with a custom icon in their place. So, I would have the close button and my custom button (with its own icon) as my window flags. The custom button would have a function connected to it whenever it is clicked.

I tried the approach outlined in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56875260/removing-icon-and-style-of-qmdisubwindow) but it is not related to customizing the window flags and I am having trouble to find a suitable approach.
The following is my code for creating multiple windows and for gathering them in a QMdiArea:

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QMdiArea,
    QMdiSubWindow,
    QWidget,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QPushButton,
)


class DetachableSubWindow(QMdiSubWindow):
    def __init__(self, widget):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWidget(widget)


class Gathered_Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.mdi_area = QMdiArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdi_area)
        self.win_instance = {}
        for i in range(1, 6):
            widget = QWidget()
            widget_layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
            widget_layout.addWidget(QPushButton("Dummy"))
            widget.setWindowTitle(f"{i}")
            self.win_instance[i] = widget

        for window_instance in self.win_instance.values():
            self.populate_window(window_instance)


    def populate_window(self, widget):
        sub_window = DetachableSubWindow(widget)
        self.mdi_area.addSubWindow(sub_window)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = Gathered_Window()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Does it have to work cross platform or only on a specific OS?

Comment: @mahkitah Cross platform please

Comment: Removing the close button also requires to remove the "system menu" icon (the one on the top left corner, showing a window context menu when clicked), but, most importantly, you cannot add custom buttons. While, theoretically, it could be possible to achieve this through a proxy style, it could only be consistent if using a defined based style (either "fusion" or "windows"), and it would still require a certain amount of "hacks" because the custom icon would still be a "close button", but you cannot just rely on a close event to trigger your custom function.

Comment: The only valid option is probably to compose/draw the title bar completely on your own, completely disregarding the default style. Which won't probably look wonderful, but it will be safer and, most importantly, consistent. You can still use the pixel metrics of the underlying QStyle to get at least the default sizes for the title bar and its contents (margins, spacings, icon sizes, etc).